# Need to calculate offsetRight in javascript

Tags: javascript, offset

I need to calculate the offsetRight of a DOM object. I already have some rather simple code for getting the offsetLeft, but there is no javascript offsetRight property. If I add the offsetLeft and offsetWidth, will that work? Or is there a better way?

```
function getOffsetLeft(obj)
{
    if(obj == null)
        return 0;
    var offsetLeft = 0;
    var tmp = obj;
    while(tmp != null)
    {
        offsetLeft += tmp.offsetLeft;
        tmp = tmp.offsetParent;
    }
    return offsetLeft;
}

function getOffsetRight(obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return 0;
    var offsetRight = 0;
    var tmp = obj;
    while (tmp != null)
    {
        offsetRight += tmp.offsetLeft + tmp.offsetWidth;
        tmp = tmp.offsetParent;
    }
    return offsetRight;    
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with "offsetRight"? The reason "left" and "top" are there is that the top an left of the window (or any container box, really) are fixed; viewframe stretching/shrinking happens (conceptually) at the right and the bottom.

Comment: I have to draw a div behind the current objects, and I'm doing in this is a right to left language. I have to know where the object (text) ends on the right to know where to position the right edge of the div. Since everything in the DOM works left to right, this is a headache.

Answer (score 13):

Cannot be more simpler than this:

```
let offsetright = window.innerWidth - obj.offsetLeft - obj.offsetWidth
```

Comment: An other way to calculate offsetRight `window.innerWidth - element.getBoundingClientRect().right`

Comment: Nice, but this example is too simple.  It doesn't account for nested elements such as when some wrapping elements have styled positions of relative.  It needs to be recursive or leverage the viewport.  It also doesn't account for overflow.

Comment: @HasanSefaOzalp I like that way too which was what I posted about 4 years ago, but it doesn't account for overflow.

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATED POST TO CLARIFY SOME GOTCHAS:**

```
// Assuming these variables:
const elem = document.querySelector('div'),
      body = document.body,
      html = document.documentElement;
```

Here are several approaches:

```
/* Leveraging the viewport AND accounting for possible overflow to the right */
const offsetRight = body.clientWidth - elem.getBoundingClientRect().right
// OR
const offsetRight = body.scrollWidth - elem.getBoundingClientRect().right
// OR
const offsetRight = html.scrollWidth - elem.getBoundingClientRect().right
```

OR

```
/*
*  Likely the safest option:
*  Doesn't depend on the viewport
*  Accounts for overflow to the right
*  Works even if the user is scrolled to the right some
*  NOTE: This ends at the <html> element,
*  but you may want to modify the code to end at the <body>
*/
const getOffsetRight = e => {
    let left = e.offsetWidth + e.offsetLeft;
    const traverse = eRef => {
        eRef = eRef.offsetParent; // `.offsetParent` is faster than `.parentElement`
        if (eRef) {
            left += eRef.offsetLeft;
            traverse(eRef);
        }
    };
    traverse(e);
    return html.scrollWidth - left;
};
const offsetRight = getOffsetRight(elem);
```

Import considerations:

- Are you using `box-sizing: border-box;` for all your elements?
- Is there `margin-left` set on the `<body>` or `<html>` elements you need to account for?
- Does the `<body>` have a fixed width but centered such as with `margin: 0 auto;`

Those things will help determine which method to use, and if you want to modify the CSS and/or the JavaScript to account for those use cases.

> **ORIGINAL POST:**
>
> A few choices:
>
> - If you want "offsetRight" relative to the viewport, use    [`element.getBoundingClientRect().right;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)
> - Your example is good simply subracting the parent width from the    element's width + offsetLeft.
> - Lastly, to be relative to the document, and to speed up traversing    (offsetParent):
>
> In this example, I'm positioning a pseudo dropdown element below the
> referenced element, but because I'm avoiding some tricky z-index
> issues and want to have the element be referenced from the right and
> expand out left, I had to append it to the body element, and the get
> the "offsetRight" from the original parent.
>
> ```
> ...
>
> // Set helper defaults
> dropdownElem.style.left = 'auto';
> dropdownElem.style.zIndex = '10';
>
> // Get the elem and its offsetParent
> let elem = dropdownElemContainer;
> let elemOffsetParent = elem.offsetParent;
>
> // Cache widths
> let elemWidth = elem.offsetWidth;
> let elemOffsetParentWidth = 0;
>
> // Set the initial offsets
> let top = elem.offsetHeight; // Because I want to visually append the elem at the bottom of the referenced bottom
> let right = 0;
>
> // Loop up the DOM getting the offsetParent elements so you don't have to traverse the entire ancestor tree
> while (elemOffsetParent) {
>   top += elem.offsetTop;
>   elemOffsetParentWidth = elemOffsetParent.offsetWidth;
>   right += elemOffsetParentWidth - (elem.offsetLeft + elemWidth); // Most important line like your own example
>   // Move up the DOM
>   elem = elemOffsetParent;
>   elemOffsetParent = elemOffsetParent.offsetParent;
>   elemWidth = elemOffsetParentWidth;
> }
>
> // Set the position and show the elem
> dropdownElem.style.top = top + 'px';
> dropdownElem.style.right = right + 'px';
> dropdownElem.style.display = 'block';
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
//Object references
function getObject(id) {
   var object = null;
   if (document.layers) {
    object = document.layers[id];
   } else if (document.all) {
    object = document.all[id];
   } else if (document.getElementById) {
    object = document.getElementById(id);
   }
   return object;
}
//Get pixel dimensions of screen
function getDimensions(){
    var winW = 630, winH = 460;
    if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
     winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
     winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
    }
    if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' && document.documentElement && document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
     winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
     winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
    }
    if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
     winW = window.innerWidth;
     winH = window.innerHeight;
    }
    return{"width":winW, "height":winH}
}
//Get the location of element
function getOffsetRight(elem){
    element=getObject(elem)
    var width = element.offsetWidth
    var right = 0;
    while (element.offsetParent) { 
        right += element.offsetLeft; 
        element = element.offsetParent;
    }
    right += element.offsetLeft;
    right = getDimensions()["width"]-right
    right -= width
    return right
}
```

This is not bullet-proof but you can usually get the "offsetRight" by calling: getOffsetRight("[object.id]")

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using some Js library then try the following functionality of prototype js 
http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element/offset/

Comment: That's just another way of doing what offsetLeft already does, and still doesn't give me the offsetRight. How is this helpful?